# SIMPLE HTML DOM PHP doesnt work/scrape

Tags: php, parsing, dom, scrape

as the title says...,this is my code

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$url1="https://www.dikaiologitika.gr/eidhseis/theseis-ergasias";

$html = file_get_html($url1); 


// Find all anchors
$anchors = $html->find("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/h3/a", 0);

echo $anchors->plaintext . '<br>';



$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

error i get is::

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in 
init.php on line 100
```

line 100 is

```
$anchors = $html->find("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/h3/a", 0);
```

What i want to scrape is the article titles along with their links, I cant see what I'm doing wrong, help please

cheers

Comment: find the elements by class name or tag name.

Comment: $anchors = $html->find("article a", 0); should be something like this

Comment: @AbidNawaz That isn't going to help much if the parser hasn't initialised correctly.

Comment: Check `allow_url_fopen` php.ini value.

Comment: Your server is having issues fetching that URL, for some reason. Could be a network configuration issue, or that site is actively blocking you, or plenty of other things. Try a simple script that just uses `file_get_contents` and then run `var_dump($http_response_header)` afterwards, it might help narrow it down.